# Am I allowed to bring whey protein from the US to Canada in my carry on baggage?

Tags: air-travel, usa, canada, food-and-drink, hand-luggage

I will be soon visiting the US, and I was wondering if I am allowed to buy a n=brand new Whey protein tub (5lb) and put in my carry on. It is a small trip and I usually just travel with my carry on only, so putting it in the hold baggage is not an option.

The protein tub costs $50 in the US and usually around $80-85 in Canada. Will I have problems or am I safe?

Answer (score 3):

The [official rule](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/food/information-for-consumers/travellers/what-can-i-bring-into-canada-/eng/1389648337546/1389648516990) for dairy products (which whey protein is) is that you can bring 20kg, valued at $20 or less, and of course you must declare it.

I wasn't able to discover what happens if you bring something valued at over $20, though my strong suspicion is that you may have to pay a duty and/or taxes on it.

In practice what *may* happen is that the customs officer will see it's canned goods from the United States and ignore it.