# I'm traveling from Canada to San Diego (and back). Can I bring protein powder in my carry-on?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I'm travelling from Canada to San Diego, and then returning from there to Canada. Can I bring protein powder in my carry-on?

1. Does it have to be packaged in the original packaging (both ways/one way)?
2. Is there a limit on volume?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53694/can-i-fly-with-white-powder-in-a-transparent-bag

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Can I bring whey protein powder on US domestic flight as carry on?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14298/can-i-bring-whey-protein-powder-on-us-domestic-flight-as-carry-on)* and/or *[Am I allowed to bring whey protein from the US to Canada in my carry on baggage?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/)*

Answer (score 0):

As long as your protein powder is legal in the United States (and Canada!), and security and customs agents are satisfied of this, you should have no problems.

I'd recommend that you carry the powder in its original container.  However, if it's not practical, you could separate it out and perhaps bring the packaging label (or take a photograph of it).  It's possible that the powder will be tested for drugs and explosives if its origin is doubted, and this may cause you some short delays, so make sure to build extra time into your travel schedule.

You should have no problem with reasonable person amounts.  If you intend to bring in commercial quantities, you will want to research whether there are any special rules pertaining to importation, and will need to declare it accordingly.